# I am using laravel auth for redirecting my users according to their type . But there i get stuck. I could not redirect user according to their type

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

Here is my routes.php file

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/login', function(){
    return view('auth.login');
});
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Here is my AuthController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'user_name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'full_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
            'full_name' => $data['full_name'],
            //'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'password' => $data['password'],
        ]);
    }


    //Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $user_name, 'password' => $password])
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->all()) {
            var_dump(Auth::user())
            if(Auth::user()->type == 'admin') {
                return "Welcome company admin let's create some user for your company";

                # code...
            } elseif(Auth::user()->type == manager) {

                return "Welcome manager let's manage your coaches";
            }elseif(Auth::user()->type == 'counterman'){
                return "Welcome counter person let's sell some ticket's";
            }else
            {
                return "Welcome online user let's make a relationship with me";
            }
            return "Gonnnaaa";
            //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }else
        {
            return "you are fucked";
        }

    }
}
```

In my project I want redirect my user to different pages according to there type . I tried to implement this in different  ways . At last I tried to use authenticate method inside AuthController as suggested in laravel doc's but I am getting AuthController not exist error . What wrong I am doing and what can be better approach in my case ? thanks in advance . I have not edited anything except AuthController and routes.

Comment: This might help you : http://laravel.io/forum/02-25-2015-laravel-5-class-authauthcontroller-does-not-exist?page=1#reply-21680

Comment: Sorry @meen I have visited this link before and this link says to override postLogin method . But what about authenticate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to implement something new by yourself, you could **create a new `TypeBasedAuthController`** that extends the `AuthController`.

Then, you would decorate its parent by implementing a `postLogin` method that calls the parent `postLogin`. After the login logic, you could change the `$redirectTo` property as you wish.

It should make sense... :)

EDIT: take a look to [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-decorator-pattern--cms-22641) if you want to know something more about the decorator pattern in PHP :)

**EDIT2 - Important**: after another deeper search, I have found a better solution. All you have to do is to overwrite [this method in your new `TypeBasedAuthController`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L108).

```
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }

    // HERE: control the user that has logged in and change the value
    // of $this-redirectTo property accordingly.

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

It should be quite clear now.

Comment: Can you give me a demo for TypeBaseAuthController(demo code) ? @Francesco . TIA :)

Comment: Didn't find a demo but it will be very simple :)
1. Create a new class `TypeBasedAuthController`, that extends the `AuthController` one;
2. Create a `postLogin` method inside of it, that will call the parent method and then, if everything went well, will check what is the current user type. Based on that value, you will be able to change `$redirectTo` accordingly :)

Comment: It will be my pleasure if you help me to write the codes inside postLogin i am not very much familiar with authController . TIA :)

Comment: @avijitbhattacharjee check edits in the answer. It should be good now.

Comment: @avijitbhattacharjee ok, let me know ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112105/discussion-between-avijit-bhattacharjee-and-francesco-malatesta).